# Script para remover readonly

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysqli

Tenho um sistema de cadastro de usuário e uma página onde mostro todos os usuários cadastrados.

Eu exibo 8 usuários por página - cada usuário tem a opção de clicar em uma âncora *Info* que detalha o usuário. Nesses detalhes há uma opção para redefinir a senha, e quando se clica no botão para redefinir a senha ele libera o input para poder ser digitado.

O problema é que como é uma paginação e são mostrados 8 usuários por página, o botão que libera o input para edição só funciona quando eu clico no 1° usuário mostrado. Exemplo:

- usuario1   usuario2   usuario3

Quero redefinir a senha do usuario2, mas quando clico no botão ele não faz nada. Porém quando eu clico para redefinir a senha do usuario1 ele libera o input para edição dos 3 usuários. Eu libero os inputs através de um *script* (ele remove o `readonly`).

### visualizaru.php:

```html
<!------------------------------------------------------- modal visualizar número --------------------------------------------------------------------->
<?php 
include_once("../../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados
     
//verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página 
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1; 
 
//seleciona todos os itens da tabela 
$cmd = "select * from tb_usuario"; 
$produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
 
//conta o total de itens 
$total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
 
//seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens 
$registros = 8; 
 
//calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima 
$numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros); 
 
//variável para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual 
$inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros; 
 
//seleciona os itens por página 
$cmd = "select * from tb_usuario limit $inicio,$registros"; 
$produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
$total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
     
//exibe os produtos selecionados 
       
                           
echo "<div class='container'>
    <div class='row pricing text-center'>

";
$cont=0;
while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_array($produtos)){
    echo"<div class='col-md-3'>
        <div class='well'>";
            echo "<h3><b>".$produto['nome']."</b></h3>
                <hr>
                    <p>Email:&nbsp;".$produto['email']."</p>
                <hr>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'>
                        <a href='deletaru.php?email=".$produto['email']."' class='btn btn-danger btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></div>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><a href='#info".$cont."' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Info</a></div>


                        <div class='modal fade' id='info".$cont."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
                <h3 class='modal-title' id='lineModalLabel' align='center'>Dados do Usuario</h3>
   
            <div class='modal-body'>
   <form method='post' action='atualizaru.php'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Nome</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='nome' class='form-control' value=".$produto['nome']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' id='letras' required>
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Email</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='email' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['email']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>
    
     <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Senha</label></center>
                    <input type='password' name='senha' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['senha']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>
    
                <div class='form-group'>
     <div class='col-xs-6'>
     <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-block' role='button' id='btnEditar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock'></span>&nbsp;Redefinir Senha</button>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='form-group'>
     <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
     <button class='btn btn-success btn-block' role='button' type='submit' value='Cadastrar' name='salvar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>&nbsp;Salvar</button>
     </center></div>
    </div>
   </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
             </div>
             </div>
             ";


            $cont++;
                }

   echo "<div class='text-center'><ul class='pagination pagination-large'>";
    for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) { 
     echo "              
  <li><a href='visualizaru.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a></li> "; 
    } 
 echo"</ul></div>
 </div>
  </div>
 ";
  
         
?>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------- Fim modal visualizar número ---------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Script usado para liberar o input:

```js
<script language='JavaScript'>
 $("#btnEditar").on('click', function() {
  $('input[name="senha"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  
});

</script>
```

Comment: O Problema é que você está trabalhando com ID, oq gera conflito na DOM, logo mais publicarei a resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicionei uma classe ao seu botão e ao seu input senha para não gerar conflitos:

```
<?php
include_once("../../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados

//verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

//seleciona todos os itens da tabela
$cmd = "select * from tb_usuario";
$produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd);

//conta o total de itens
$total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos);

//seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens
$registros = 8;

//calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
$numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

//variável para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
$inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros;

//seleciona os itens por página
$cmd = "select * from tb_usuario limit $inicio,$registros";
$produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd);
$total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos);

//exibe os produtos selecionados


echo "<div class='container'>
    <div class='row pricing text-center'>

";
$cont=0;
while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_array($produtos)){
    echo"<div class='col-md-3'>
        <div class='well'>";
    echo "<h3><b>".$produto['nome']."</b></h3>
                <hr>
                    <p>Email:&nbsp;".$produto['email']."</p>
                <hr>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'>
                        <a href='deletaru.php?email=".$produto['email']."' class='btn btn-danger btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a></div>
                        <div class='col-xs-6'><a href='#info".$cont."' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Info</a></div>


                        <div class='modal fade' id='info".$cont."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
          <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
                <h3 class='modal-title' id='lineModalLabel' align='center'>Dados do Usuario</h3>

            <div class='modal-body'>
            <form method='post' action='atualizaru.php'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Nome</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='nome' class='form-control' value=".$produto['nome']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' id='letras' required>
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Email</label></center>
                    <input type='text' name='email' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['email']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                 <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-12'><center>
                    <label for='exampleInputPassword1'>Senha</label></center>
                    <input type='password' name='senha' class='form-control senha' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['senha']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
                    <br></div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-block btnEditar' role='button' id='btnEditar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock'></span>&nbsp;Redefinir Senha</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'><center>
                    <button class='btn btn-success btn-block' role='button' type='submit' value='Cadastrar' name='salvar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>&nbsp;Salvar</button>
                    </center></div>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
             </div>
             </div>
             ";


    $cont++;
}

echo "<div class='text-center'><ul class='pagination pagination-large'>";
for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) {
    echo "              
        <li><a href='visualizaru.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a></li> ";
}
echo"</ul></div>
    </div>
        </div>
    ";


?>
```

E no js iremos trabalhar com elas dessa maneira:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
    $(".btnEditar").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.senha').removeAttr('readonly');

    });

</script>
```